# Spring saml, second local SP - entity alias and context provider

Tags: spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I have system with two loadbalancer exposing application for separate networks.

In application spring-saml extension is used for authentication with IdP (one visible from both networks).
For first location all working as expected - default SP with entityId=exampleSP1.

When I configure second SP metadata (local with different entityId=exampleSP2) and call it using /saml/login/alias/exampleSP2
Application receive successful response from IdP but during SAMLCredential validation exception is thrown:
"SAML message intended destination endpoint did not match recipient endpoint"

When using second SP destination endpoint is different from configured in contextProviderLB and exception occur.

Is a way to define separated contextProviderLB depends on which SP is used (or initial URL) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting an issue in https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES-150 which is now fixed in trunk. Please update your Spring SAML. And thank you leaving your comment in Jira.

Comment: Yes, you have partial right (there is my comment for that issue). But this don't resolve my problem. I resolve it by configure separate set of all saml beans - with different metadata and loadBalancerContex. Moreover I must define own authentication provider which switch between two defined with appropriate entityId.